# Video no play in Android after one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

This is code

```
 <div class="video-block">
     <iframe width="920" height="572" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Bp3lxx7kkPs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="video-mask">
            <div class="play-block">
                <button type="button" class="play-btn">
                    <i class="play_icon"></i>
                </button>
                <p>Video Presentation</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is JS

```
$(".play-block").on("click", function(playBtnEvent) {

    playBtnEvent.preventDefault();

    parentEl = $(this).closest(".video-block");

    indexVideoBox = parentEl.index(".video-block");

    videoIdAttr = "video_" + indexVideoBox;

    parentEl.find("iframe").attr("id", videoIdAttr);

    $(this).closest(".video-mask").fadeOut(300);

    $("#" + videoIdAttr)[0].src += "?rel=0&autoplay=1";            

});
```

When I click on `.play-block` i can start video in iframe. This works in Desktop. In smart is need to click on `.play-block` after in iframe to. 
For playing this video is need to click ones.
How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What is the problem?

Comment: I have video from You Tube. When i click on mask my video must be stared.  In the desktop this works. In Smarts this click event is not sent to iframe. After of fadeOut of the maks is need to click in iframe separately.